# Typescript error on creating dynamic components and module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

Im trying to add the component and module dynamically as shown below

Component:

```
protected createNewComponent (tmpl:string) {
  @Component({
      selector: 'dynamic-component',
      template: tmpl,
      providers: [{provide: CustomDynamicComponent, useExisting CustomDynamicComponent}]
  })
  class CustomDynamicComponent  implements IHaveDynamicData {
      @Input()  public entity: any;
  };
  // a component for this particular template
  return CustomDynamicComponent;
}
```

Here tmpl template is a dynamic string.

Module:

```
protected createComponentModule (componentType: any) {
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
      componentType
    ],
  })
  class RuntimeComponentModule
  {
  }
  // a module for just this Type
  return RuntimeComponentModule;
}
```

Here componentType is the component I want to create.

Now, creating component and module dynamically using

```
let type   = this.createNewComponent(template);
let module = this.createComponentModule(type);
```

and compiling the markup using

```
this.compiler
        .compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
        .then((moduleWithFactories) => {})
```

On compiling this code, Im observing typescript compilation errors as shown below.

[image]
[image]

How to get rid of this compilation error in angular version14.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do something that complicated :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class Foo {
  rand = Math.random();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: '<div #container></div>',
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private environement: EnvironmentInjector
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.environement.runInContext(() => { // important part to allow DI with inject()
      // Define the component using Component decorator.
      const component = Component({
        selector: 'test',
        template:
          '<div>This is the dynamic template. Test value: {{test}}</div>',
        styles: [':host {color: red}'],
        providers: [{ provide: Foo, useClass: Foo }],
      })(
        class {
          private foo = inject(Foo);

          constructor() {
            console.log(this.foo.rand);
          }

          test = 'some value';
        }
      );

      // Define the module using NgModule decorator.
      const module = NgModule({ declarations: [component] })(class {});

      const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(component, {
        injector: this.injector,
        ngModuleRef: createNgModuleRef(module, this.injector),
      });
      setTimeout(() => (componentRef.instance.test = 'some other value'), 2000);
    });
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qexlu4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: I would like to also include providers array here, to provide the useExisting component class as below.  providers: [{
                provide: MyCompClass,
                useExisting: MyComp
         }]. But this is not working. On adding providers, Im able to see the same compile errors.

Comment: why do you need provider that basically does nothing? you can still inject component instance by its class in its components subtree without that provider

Comment: @bvakiti `useExisting` is meant to map one token to another, that can't work like that. And what isn't working with my example, please give us more details.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I would like to use this component by other class too. So I want to add this component to providers array, may be using useClass

Comment: @bvakiti Since you create your class yourself, you can't use the traditionnal dependency injection. But since Angular 14.2, there is a solid alternative with `inject()` and `EnvironmentInjector.runInContext()`. Please see my update !